# Is it possible to pass a module's function as functionName of SpreadsheetApp's menu?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've code like this:

```
MyCompany = (MyCompany || {});
MyCompany.init = function () {
    Logger.log('init');  
};

function onOpen() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menus = [{
        name: "Init",
        functionName: 'how to call MyCompany.init without creating function?'
    }];
    spreadsheet.addMenu("Test", menus);
};
```

Is it possible to call MyCompany.init without creating another function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, it's impossible. The function, which name is used in `functionName` parameter should be defined in global scope. Even though the object is defined in global scope, you can't use its function for using in menu.

It's **not stated** in the official scripting reference (maybe it is, but it's hidden very good then), but it can be proved by some simple tests, like moving function between different scopes and seeing if the script still works.

The best think you can do here (I suppose) is to create a global function, which will call that `MyCompany.init` like this:

```
MyCompany = (MyCompany || {});
MyCompany.init = function () {
    Logger.log('init');  
};

function callInit() {
    MyCompany.init();
}

function onOpen() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menus = [{
        name: "Init",
        functionName: 'how to call MyCompany.init without creating function?'
    }];
    spreadsheet.addMenu("Test", menus);
};
```

That way your namespace organization will remain.